# "Console" showing nil value for variable whereas "Variables view" showing values for the same

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

During debugging I noticed that console was showing **nil** values for all the properties of an object when I used `po` command but it passed `!=nil` validation so I checked the **Variables view** and it showed that the properties were not actually nil but had some value

[image]

I saw a few questions which specified to check *Optimization level* in *Build Settings* but they were set to what was expected. I am using Xcode 11.5

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using closure as asynchronous to fetch the data. That is why you see nil and your values are not in scope in LLDB in debug mode.

[Swift: Asynchronous callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25055313/14531220)